Как установить aiogram 3.16.0 в iSH
При попытки установить aiogram 3.16.0 возникает ошибка и следующий stack trace:
localhost:~# pip install aiogram
Collecting aiogram
  Downloading aiogram-3.16.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.6 kB)
Collecting aiofiles<24.2,>=23.2.1 (from aiogram)
  Using cached aiofiles-24.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<3.12,>=3.9.0 (from aiogram)
  Downloading aiohttp-3.11.11-cp39-cp39-musllinux_1_2_i686.whl.metadata (7.7 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2023.7.22 (from aiogram)
  Using cached certifi-2024.12.14-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
Collecting magic-filter<1.1,>=1.0.12 (from aiogram)
  Using cached magic_filter-1.0.12-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
Collecting pydantic<2.11,>=2.4.1 (from aiogram)
  Downloading pydantic-2.10.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (29 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions<=5.0,>=4.7.0 (from aiogram)
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting aiohappyeyeballs>=2.3.0 (from aiohttp<3.12,>=3.9.0->aiogram)
  Using cached aiohappyeyeballs-2.4.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.1 kB)
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2 (from aiohttp<3.12,>=3.9.0->aiogram)
  Using cached aiosignal-1.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
Collecting async-timeout<6.0,>=4.0 (from aiohttp<3.12,>=3.9.0->aiogram)
  Using cached async_timeout-5.0.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0 (from aiohttp<3.12,>=3.9.0->aiogram)
  Using cached attrs-24.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1 (from aiohttp<3.12,>=3.9.0->aiogram)
  Using cached frozenlist-1.5.0-cp39-cp39-musllinux_1_2_i686.whl.metadata (13 kB)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5 (from aiohttp<3.12,>=3.9.0->aiogram)
  Using cached multidict-6.1.0-cp39-cp39-musllinux_1_2_i686.whl.metadata (5.0 kB)
Collecting propcache>=0.2.0 (from aiohttp<3.12,>=3.9.0->aiogram)
  Using cached propcache-0.2.1-cp39-cp39-musllinux_1_2_i686.whl.metadata (9.2 kB)
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.17.0 (from aiohttp<3.12,>=3.9.0->aiogram)
  Using cached yarl-1.18.3-cp39-cp39-musllinux_1_2_i686.whl.metadata (69 kB)
Collecting annotated-types>=0.6.0 (from pydantic<2.11,>=2.4.1->aiogram)
  Using cached annotated_types-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)

Collecting pydantic-core==2.27.2 (from pydantic<2.11,>=2.4.1->aiogram)
  Downloading pydantic_core-2.27.2.tar.gz (413 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      error: failed to parse manifest at /tmp/pip-install-brmkojt7/pydantic-core_223719ccac4145fd95b89dc1602722ad/Cargo.toml
      
      Caused by:
        feature edition2021 is required
      
        this Cargo does not support nightly features, but if you
        switch to nightly channel you can add
        cargo-features = ["edition2021"] to enable this feature
       maturin failed
        Caused by: Cargo metadata failed. Does your crate compile with cargo build?
        Caused by: cargo metadata exited with an error:
      Error running maturin: Command '['maturin', 'pep517', 'write-dist-info', '--metadata-directory', '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-y7dg1nw1', '--interpreter', '/usr/bin/python3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      Running maturin pep517 write-dist-info --metadata-directory /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-y7dg1nw1 --interpreter /usr/bin/python3
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details

Перед этой ошибкой, от меня требовалось установить rust, а именно установщик пакетов cargo, я установил cargo 1.52.1, а тот в при установки своих зависимостей подтянул rust.
Я так понял, что не удалось подготовить метаданные pydantic_core-2.27.2, о  чем говорит строка:
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error

Далее идет следующая подсказка:
this Cargo does not support nightly features, but if you
        switch to nightly channel you can add
        cargo-features = ["edition2021"] to enable this feature
       maturin failed

Я понял так, Этот Cargo не поддерживает ночные функции - это возможно значит следующие, нужно добавить cargo-features = ["edition"] во все файлы cargo.toml, вероятно я ошибаюсь. Я не разбираюсь в .toml и не понимаю что куда и самое главное зачем во все файлы это добавлять, поэтому,  чтобы не запутаться я решил поискать ответы в сети, думал что как всегда найду похожую проблему, увы :(
Ответа в сети я не нашел, искал даже на зарубежных сайтах.
Моя цель установки aiogram - у меня есть бот уже написанный на aiogram 3.16.0 и я планирую запустить его на айфоне, telebot вроде как устанавливается на iSH вообще без проблем, вроде как, потому что н youtube какой-то парень запускал эхо-бота на telebot.
Я бы запустил и на telebot, но как я понял, aiogram асинхронный и более полная библиотека для ботов от которых требуется работать с несколькими пользователями.
Прошу помогите пожалуйста.
Дополнительно нашел ещё вот что:
Я решил обновить rust как рекомендовали тут(ведь такая ошибка как у меня из-за старого rust могла возникнуть) и оказывается что с cargo, rust не был установлен. На форме нашел обсуждения 2018 года по поводу того что rust нельзя установить на iSH из-за того что нет 32 битной версии установочного файла, а iSH работает как 32 битная оболочка Alpine.
